# cmake file generation -- a more elegant alternative?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I would like to get what you see below in the Makefile but with cmake:

```
/// Makefile
all: main

header_moc.h : header.h
    ./mokker.sh header_moc.h

main : header_moc.h header.h
    g++ main.cpp
```

The file contents follow:

```
/// header.h
void foo(){}
```

The only cpp:

```
/// main.cpp
#include "header.h"
#include "header_moc.h"
int main(int, char**){
    return 0;
}
```

The scripts generates the dummy _moc file:

```
/// mokker.sh
touch $1
```

This is the cmake file:

```
/// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(test)

macro(generate_file target name)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${name}_moc.h
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mokker.sh ${name}_moc.h  
        DEPENDS ${name}.h
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
    add_custom_target(${target}_${name}_moc DEPENDS ${name}_moc.h)
    add_dependencies(${target} ${target}_${name}_moc)
endmacro()

add_executable(test main.cpp header.h)
generate_file(test header)
```

- **Is it really necessary to do that extra "add_custom_target"?**
- **Can you propose any more elegant solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, add_custom_target is not necessary. And by the way, your CMakeLists.txt isn't completely correct.

Take a look at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_generate_a_source_file_during_the_build.3F

As you may see, a generated file, `foo.c` is mentioned in the list of program sources `ADD_EXECUTABLE(foo foo.c)`, and, that's why it's automatically put into the list of `foo` dependencies.

Comment: Hello there, yes, that was intentional. The reason for which I did it that way is that I don't want to do it at an add_executable level. If I do it there, those auto-generated files will be visible in the project explorer of IDEs (and they'll think it's a good idea to edit them). 
Unfortunately, _add_dependencies(test foo.c)_ does not work. I find this a bit puzzling

Comment: `add_dependencies` as the documentation says is for top-level targets only. So if you need to use `add_dependencies`, then you have to create custom top level targets for it (as you do). Alternatively you may use `add_custom_command(TARGET <target> PRE_BUILD ...)` (it creates a top-level target too) but in this case the build system will always rebuild the target (i.e. re-generate ${name}_moc.h), whether you changed the source or not.

Comment: I see, I guess then I covered all the possible options. You either have to do what I showed you, or the one you mention above.